# file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded with imgur API

Tags: php, file-upload, file-get-contents

I'm trying to create an app to upload profile images to imgur but I'm having a problem.

```
if (isset($_POST['uploadprofileimg'])) {
   $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['profileimg']['tmp_name']));

   $options = array('http' => array(
       'method' => "POST",
       'header' => "Authorization: Bearer sdf541gs6df51gsd1bsb16etb16teg1etr1ge61g\n",
       "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       'content' => $image
   ));

   $context = stream_context_create($options);

   $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";

   $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, FALSE, $context);
}
```

I'm getting this notice:

> Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded in
>   C:\WebServer\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs\html\www\SocialNetwork\my-account.php
>   on line 17

even though this doesn't break my app, it's annoying. How can I fix it?

I've tried to add "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n", and "Connection: close" to the header part but it doesn't seem to fix it!!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try replacing the options array with:

```
$options = array('http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' =>
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
        "Authorization: Bearer sdf541gs6df51gsd1bsb16etb16teg1etr1ge61g\n",
    'content' => $image
));
```

Comment: I had to slightly change your code, but in the end it fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Works, thanks. It seems that Content-Type must be the very first row or it wont recognize.